# Create bridge with Wifi

Tags: wifi, bridge

I was using a bridge the Ethernet port, but I need to change.
I am trying with this config without success:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#iface lo inet dhcp


# wifi wlp2s0
auto wlp2s0
allow-hotplug wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet manual
#       wpa-ssid boxssid
#       wpa-psk key

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
bridge_ports wlp2s0
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
        bridge_stp off
        address 192.168.1.161
        network 192.168.1.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        wpa-ssid boxssid
        wpa-psk key
```

As you see I made some tests with the code to connect to the wifi in different places.
Thanks

Comment: There's a de facto limit with Wifi: only the Access Point can bridge a Wifi interface. A STAtion client cannot do this. If you are attempting to bridge while not being *the* AP, this requires changes to the AP too as well as adequate hardware/driver support on AP and client to use 4 address mode. Is your AP also running an actual programmable OS like OpenWRT + hostapd? Else forget about it.  Wifi is not Ethernet. It uses 3 or 4 MAC addresses, but the de facto use is only 3 (=> limited): https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/four-layer-2-addresses-in-802-11-frame-header